# How does meteor perform with many subscriptions over larger documents?

Tags: javascript, meteor, websocket

I'm currently designing a database for a fairly large meteor app, and we're debating whether Meteor will perform better using more subscriptions, to collections of tiny documents, or fewer subscriptions to collections of larger documents.

Some of these documents could in end become quite large, such as listings of user favourites or preferences, that would only be viewable to the individual user in a particular view.

In terms of numbers we're talking about 10 subscriptions, at least four of which would not be consistently subscribed too, returning only a single larger document in particular views.

Versus 4 subscriptions to collections of possibly quite large documents, (I realize that those individual view would probably render faster having the data already on the client).

Any insights or empirical data would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: please note I'm looking for specific insight based on experience and /or data, rather than opinion. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not a complete answer. I'm currently in the process of solving this problem myself.

I have some experience with larger data sets. I subscribe to a single collection without any restrictions:

```
Meteor.publish('collectionName', function () {
    return collectionName.find();
});
```

My collection contains **400 documents** with a total size of approximately **600KB** (after dumping the collection using [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)). With about **100 users** in the system (using it daily from different continents) we do have a few performance issues:

- When I load the page displaying the 400 items, you can watch the list being populated.
- It is also important what you do with the 400 documents. Each of my entries is a fairly complex DOM node with multiple helpers executed for each item.

Generating the DOM takes some time and causes a peak on the clients CPU. Also a lot of data is transferred to the client.

A few ideas to solve the problems:

- Using pagination (e.g. package [`alethes:pages`](https://atmospherejs.com/alethes/pages)) to *prevent intense client computation*.
- Use a separate publication/subscription for a list view only including the fields necessary to display the list items to *reduce the size of each document*
- Only publish/subscribe to documents that are viewable to the current user (e.g. checking for login status, access permissions, etc) to *reduce the number of documents*.
- Cache the subscription: https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager (haven't tried that yet)

Comment: Thanks Peter, thats good feedback, not a complete picture in terms of my initial question, but definitely a great start.   Whats different I thin about our app, is that all that data isn't available on every screen ,and there are different discrete sets, but very useful to hear your experience.

Comment: Well if you have discrete sets of parts of the data then the subscription stuff is even easier. I have one view where I need MOST of the data, which prevents me from using some clever subscription. Ideally, you have very specific subscriptions to small subsets of documents (query) and only fields that you need (projection) to minimize transferred data. Additionally having more precise/specific subscriptions increases data security.

Comment: The benefits of using discrete specific subscriptions are many, and why I'm asking the question, I'm really interesting 10 - 15 subs with small docs (that can and will of course be paged etc) vs 3 or 4 subs with much bigger documents - not all the data being need all of the time.